# Unable to view .aspx file as guest through web browser - IIS always pops up authetication required window

Tags: asp.net, windows, authentication, iis-6, windows-server-2003

I have a new dedicating hosting server and am running IIS 6 on windows 2003.

I've set all the user permissions to the web-directory to allow an internet guest user to access it.

.htm and .asp files are able to be viewed without any problems.  Browsing the .aspx file/application locally under the admin authentication works without any problems.

As soon as I try to access a aspx file through the external internet (as any normal guest would do), a authentication required window pops up.  WHY?!

AuthDiag reveals authentication anonymous access is denied..... even though I have enabled anonymous access in IIS... but then how are the .htm and .asp files being displayed!

Comment: Have you checked the Authentication settings for the site in IIS?  If it is set to Windows Authentication, I believe this may be one of the causes of this.

Comment: I have anonymous access enabled in iis - where can I disable Windows authentication? thanks for your response!

Comment: You using No or Forms authentication?

If you are using no authentication, change your web.config <authentication mode="None"> (I imagine you have "Windows"). Otherwise, if you are using Forms authentication, change it to <authentication mode="Forms">, but you will have to set up Forms if you have not already. Then redeploy it.

Comment: @gangelo you should post that as an answer.

Comment: Did changing it to `none` solve the issue?  I'm having this problem too.

Answer (score 0):

You using No or Forms authentication? If you are using no authentication, change your web.config  (I imagine you have "Windows"). Otherwise, if you are using Forms authentication, change it to , but you will have to set up Forms if you have not already. Then redeploy it.

Comment: It's still not working... and now I've done something so that the whole site is asking for authentication... this is my web config <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="None" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>

Comment: @Huynhtj - you using Winforms, MVC#?

Comment: @Huynhtj  - Forget it, just realized that was a silly question.  This document is a little old, but check it out; I believe it may give yo some direction: [link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292114%28v=vs.71%29.aspx[/link]

Comment: this is insane... i've read through a bit - I thought my isur_<guest name> passwords were out of sync - ie. the IIS password and SAM password - but i've just fixed that and I'm still having problems... argh.  hmmm... what to do....

Comment: You only using 1 web.config I assume?